# Angular 9 - is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular9

It was working till angular 7 now after updating it it throws error of unknown elements. It's happening for shared modules.

Reproducible Code: - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pb3eea

So I have a parent component 'Parent', 
child component to be used inside router of 'Parent' - 'Child'
a shared component to be used inside parent and child both - 'Shared'

So I have imported in both modules of parent and child. (As using lazy modules), in parent it works but not in child.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestChildRoutingModule} from './test-child.routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule,
        TestChildRoutingModule
    ],
    exports: [
    ]
})
export class TestChildModule { }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the declaration of TestChildComponent in the TestChildModule

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      TestChildComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule,
        TestChildRoutingModule
    ],
    exports: [
      TestChildComponent
    ]
})
export class TestChildModule { }
```

Here is the fixed [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5kcajq?file=src/app/child/test.child.module.ts)

Comment: I was about to post the same :) +1

Comment: That was a very silly mistake. Thank you Sajeethran and @pradeep